# Find a positive-definite scalar product for which $F:\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ is symmetrical

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Let $F$ be an operator (in $\mathbb{R^3}$) whose eigenvalues are: $\lambda_1 =1$, $\lambda_2 = -1$, whose eigenspaces are: $V_1= \{(x_1, x_2, x_2): x_1-2x_2+x_3=0\}$ and $V_2=span\{(2,0,1)\}$.

*- Find a positive-definite scalar product for which $F$ is symmetrical.*

$F$ isn't simmetrycal for the inner product because its eigenvectors aren't orthogonal to each other: $(2,1,0)(2,0,1)\neq0$ for example. However, since $F$ is diagonalizable (we can see it with easy calculations), there is an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors for which $F$ is symmetrical. How to find a positive-definite scalar product in that basis?

Comment: What does "$F$ is symmetrical" mean?

Comment: Seems like you’re coming at this from the wrong direction. Your task is to define a scalar product relative to which the two eigenspaces are orthogonal. Think about what the matrix of the associated quadratic form might look like relative to an eigenbasis.

Comment: Easy way is to pick eigenvectors to be orthonormal in the new inner product. This uniquely determines the inner product once you extend this definition bilinearly. This bilinear extension can be written in a nice way in terms of a matrix.